# Foreach gives error : wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command" in TCL

Tags: foreach, tcl

I have a simple foreach loop in a .tcl code it gives error and I can't figure out what is wrong. I tried adding / before the $ and still got the same result.

```
set nodes "NODE1 NODE2"        
foreach node $nodes{
    PINS_DOC::DSC $node(mcemonInterface) $node(ipAddr) 1 ENTERED -timeout 300
}
```

Comment: There is a missing space between `$nodes` and `{`. If you fix that, the command will most likely work.

Comment: yes the space got rid of that error but now I have another error. can't read "node(mcemonInterface)": variable isn't array
I guess I have to change the format of the logic all together

Answer (score 1):

In addition to fix the missing space after $nodes in the foreach and guessing arrays NODE1 and NODE2 are well defined (you can verify this using the command *parray*) you can do

```
PINS_DOC::DSC [set $node\(mcemonInterface)] [set $node\(ipAddr)] 1 ENTERED -timeout 300
```

More about [dereferencing variables](http://wiki.tcl.tk/8662).

Saludos,